# how to upload image from front end to the server image folder in php

Tags: php

I am new to php my question is i want the user to upload the image(from front end) and it should store in the folder i.e. in server.How can it be achieve.I know how to store the url in database.But I want to store the image in the folder which is in the server can it be achieved.

Comment: The internet is full of examples on how to implement a file upload with php. None of all those pages helped? _Why not?_

Comment: Appy, you will get better answers if you post your code (click "edit" under your question and paste your code, for example, the code to store the url).

Answer (score 0):

You can find out example of upload image from AngularJs front-end to server using php here: https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload